# Regex to match url directory path without match file name

Tags: java, regex

I want a regex that will match

`https://example.com/studio/` or `https://example.com/studio` without matching `https://example.com/studio/path-to-file-blah-blah` or `https://example.com/studio/path-to-file-blah-blah.html`

I tries `https?:\/\/(?:w{3}[.])?example[.]com\/studio\S*` but it's matching both groups above.

I have also tried `https?:\/\/(?:w{3}[.])?example[.]com\/studio\/?` and it was able to match only the first group. But the problem is matching only the second group. Please how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you need to parse the URL from unstructured text. Assuming there's a space character, new line character, or the end of the string the following should work for you. If there's a period or other character directly after the URL this will fail, but it's easy to modify to support additional terminating characters.

```
https?:\/\/(?:w{3}[.])?example[.]com\/studio\/?(?:\s|$)
```

`(?:\s|$)`  Just says match a space character (which includes line endings line a new line character) OR match the end of the string.

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/g4QJVR/1)

**EDIT**

I think you're saying group 2 is:

```
https://example.com/studio/path-to-file-blah-blah
https://example.com/studio/path-to-file-blah-blah.html
```

To match these, you'll need the following regex:

```
https?:\/\/(?:w{3}[.])?example[.]com\/studio\/\S+
```

The only change I made was the last character was `\S*`, but it should be `\S+`.

`*` means 0 or more

`+` means 1 or more.

Hopefully this touches on what you're looking for. If I'm still off, if you label the groups it'd help me understand so I can write the correct regex.

Comment: Thanks but your regex matches matches the first group but like I said in my question I have already found the solution to that. I only need to match the second group.

Comment: My apologies, I must have misunderstood what your after. I was thinking you wanted to match only `https://example.com/studio/` or `https://example.com/studio`. What other cases are you trying to match? The regexes you provided would match `https://example.com/studio/path-to-file-blah-blah` whereas mine will not.

Comment: In my question I wrote two regexes: `https?:\/\/(?:w{3}[.])?example[.]com\/studio\S*` and `https?:\/\/(?:w{3}[.])?example[.]com\/studio\/?`. The first matches both groups while the second one matches the first group only. So I want a regex that'll match only the second group.

Answer (score 0):

Further expanding on Nathan's answer, you can change the end of the RegEx to not capture the trailing space or new line. This will match the first two cases:

```
https?:\/\/(?:w{3}[.])?example[.]com\/studio\/?(?=\s|$)
```

To match only the second case, use this:

```
https?:\/\/(?:w{3}[.])?example[.]com\/studio(?=[^\/])
```